# JMS client app Error. Failed to connect using URL <t3://localhost:7001>

Tags: c#, jms, weblogic

I'm writing client application on C# to connect to my local JMS (Weblogic Server 12c).
I try to use sample code from here

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13746/app_examples.htm#JMSDN180

But on line

```
context = ContextFactory.CreateContext(paramMap);
```

I have error:

> *An exception of type 'WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.TransportException' occurred in
>   WebLogic.Messaging.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Failed to connect using URL t3://localhost:7001*

may be I need to somehow configure the server?

Inner exception of this error is

> *Failed to create T3 connection*

and the inner exception of this is

> *Unknown connection parameters MS:10000000*

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, you need to supply the username and password as connection params. Specifically:

```
paramMap[Constants.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL] = username;
paramMap[Constants.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS] = password;
```

This [Oracle example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13746/develop.htm#JMSDN131) contains more information than the link in your question.