# Weblogic 12c Failed to Create Context: Unknown connection parameters MS:10000000

Tags: c#, .net, weblogic12c

We are deploying a .NET application onto a server which talks to a Weblogic 12c JMS server instance. We are attempting to create a context using the following code:

```
IDictionary<string, Object> paramMap = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
paramMap[Constants.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL] = "weblogic";
paramMap[Constants.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS] = "password";
paramMap[Constants.Context.PROVIDER_URL] = "t3://localhost:8833";

IContext context = ContextFactory.CreateContext(paramMap);
```

When the CreateContext() method runs, we receive the following exception:

> WebLogic.Messaging.MessageException: Problem creating context
>   --> System.Exception: Unknown connection parameters MS:10000000
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.T3Connection.CheckConnectionParams(String input)
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.T3Connection.ProcessLoginResponse(Stream in_Renamed)
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.T3Connection..ctor(String hostAddress, Int32 port, Int32 soketTO, T3PeerInfo peerInfo, SByte serviceId)
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.TransportSPIImpl.StartClient(Stringhost, Int32 port, TransportUserCfgParameters paras, IMarshalReadableFactory mrf, ITransportThreadPool pool)
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Physical.T3TransportFactory.CreateT3Transport(String host, Int32 port, TransportUserCfgParameters paras)
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Physical.T3TransportFactory.CreateT3Transport(IDictionary'2 paramMap) ---> System.Exception: Unknown connection parameters MS:10000000
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.T3Connection.CheckConnectionParams(String input)
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.T3Connection.ProcessLoginResponse(Stream in_Renamed)
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.T3Connection..ctor(String hostAddress, Int32 port, Int32 soketTO, T3PeerInfo peerInfo, SByte serviceId)
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.T3Client.TransportSPIImpl.StartClient(Stringhost, Int32 port, TransportUserCfgParameters paras, IMarshalReadableFactory mrf, ITransportThreadPool pool)
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Physical.T3TransportFactory.CreateT3Transport(String host, Int32 port, TransportUserCfgParameters paras)
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.Physical.T3TransportFactory.CreateT3Transport(IDictionary`2 paramMap)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at WebLogic.Messaging.ContextFactory.CreateContext(IDictionary'2 paramMap)

What is puzzling is that we have six other servers which use the same code, and the context is created successfully in each case. That suggests some issue with the setup of Weblogic, but at this point we're scratching our heads.

I searched online and found very little information regarding the cause of this exception, other than [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232700/jms-client-app-error-failed-to-connect-using-url-t3-localhost7001), which isn't very helpful.

Does anyone have any insight regarding the cause of this exception, and more importantly, how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution. We were using V1.3.1 of Weblogic.Messaging.dll. When we upgraded to V1.3.4, this problem was resolved.

Comment: hi, facing the same issue. but im using V1.3.4 dll only,. any thing other than can be fix?